How to type hint an attribute that can be assigned with a value of super type?
I am working with a C++ library wrapped for Python.
The library defines classes, each with many attributes that are like Python standard types but with a few extra methods. eg in the Python stubs "String" inherits from the standard "str"
class String(str):
    def get_key(self) -> str:
        """Return the key for this property."""
        ...

and then a class might have attributes of type "String", eg
class Asset:
    name: String = ''
    ...

The C++ code supports getting and setting these attribute values using regular Python types. So I can do
my_asset.name = 'Foo'
print(my_asset.name) # Foo
print(type(my_asset.name))  # String
print(my_asset.name.get_key())  # name

However Python type-checking (Pylance in this case) doesn't like the first line above. It says

Cannot assign to attribute "name" for class "Asset"
"str" is incompatible with "String" PylancereportAttributeAccessIssue
(variable) name: str

Is there a way I can modify my Python stubs so that type-checkers will understand that String is compatible with str, not just that in inherits from it?

In the example my_asset.name will the result be a String or a str? If it’s a str, then in what context could you actually use the extra methods of String, e.g. get_key?

my_asset.name is a String. Even if I assign a str value to it, because it actually exists in C++, when I get the value from it it's a String again.
At any point I can do something like:
    my_asset.name = 'hello'
    foo = my_asset.name()
    bar = foo.get_key()

Note though if I tried to set it to an int, (my_asset.name = 1) I'd get a ValueError from the C++ wrapper.

Sorry I have completely failed to figure out formatting for this comment. I've improved my example in the original question to answer your question @nneonneo.

You can declare name as property with the getter returning String but the setter accepting str:
class Asset:
    @property
    def name(self) -> String:
        ...

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value: str) -> None:
        ...


Do note that this has an unfortunate side effect of making .name accessible from the class itself: reveal_type(Asset.name) # property.

Thank you both for your suggestions. When I turn on reportPropertyTypeMismatch in the Pyright Playground for that example, value: str in the setter is flagged as an error. That is still a big improvement: an error on a single line in a factory can be ignored to allow for correct type-checking in the rest of the codebase. The problem of the type in the class itself is a deal breaker for me. I've been trying to use this answer to improve this but so far it has the problem that once I assign a str to my attr, Pyright thinks it's a str, not a String.

My Pyright playground url is far too long to link here so I made a Gist with the code I've tried so far.

And this won't work for mypy, unfortunately:( Asymmetric properties are still not supported there. https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3004
